# Trying to get the privacy settings for an app using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, publish-actions

I am using the Javascript SDK to log in to facebook and request 'publish_actions' permissions for my application.  I have everything working and can post photos to my application no problem.  I use my own dialog to let them set a comment and set privacy setting to "Just Me", "Friends" or "Public".

When a user first attempts to connect to facebook from my web app, they are asked to set the privacy setting level when posting photos (Just Me, Friends, Public, etc).  The issue I am having is that I want to be able to get that information later when the user posts a photo through my app so I can see what privacy setting are available for my dialog.  For example:

A user logs in to my app and for publish_actions chooses "Friends" as the privacy setting.  Later on if they are running my app, I give them a choice to pick "Only Me", "Friends" or "Public" but I need to know that "Public" is not allowed for that user.  Currently if they choose public it will default back to "Friends" since that is what was picked when they connected through my app initially.

I have found examples of accessing the permissions in the privacy_setting table using FQL but not for a particular app (also that looks to be going away with versions after 2.0 according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy_setting/.

I have not been able to find an end point in the Graph Api to provide the apps privacy setting for a given app.

Would appreciate if anyone knows how to get this.

Comment: That information is not available via API.

Comment: @CBroe, can you please provide some prooflink to this?

Comment: @voiger: Have you heard the saying, _“you can’t prove a negative”_ …? If it was available, it would be in the API docs.

Comment: @CBroe, I couldn't find it either...

Comment: It's completely ridiculous that there's no way to do this...

Comment: Any progress on this? I have been scouring their API docs and have also not found anything yet.